# To what extent does express-generator need to be installed or used in Express 4.0?

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to Express and running Express 4.0.I have installed express-generator globally with npm and got the "welcome to express" running locally. I am making the assumption that although after Express 4.0 we need to both install Express and express-generator globally it is still possible to omit using the site generator and simply write the few pages needed for serving  JSON and then a Javascript client that calls into that API, using AngularJS for example. Is this assumption correct? For example would the code on this [tutorial](http://www.marcusoft.net/2014/02/mnb-express.html) still be valid to use and run? If yes, does express-generator need to be installed or used in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely correct.

Express generator is mostly a script generating the initial *hello world* code for you.

It can save you some time, if you do this often, and is also a good starting point for new people who do not know how to write that initial code themselves.

If you are to write the code yourself starting from the *white paper*, then there is no need to install generator.